# Symfony - form builder : ChoiceType always NULL after submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I work with symfony and I have a form with a ChoiceType, the choices are coming as array from a fields from an other entity

**FormType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
       $builder->add('paq', ChoiceType::class, array(
                 'choices' => $options['data_array'],
             ));
}
```

**Twig**

```
 <form action="{{ path('ligne_panier_create', { 'id': opProd.produit.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} >
      {{form_start(form)}}
            <div class="form-group">
                 <h5>Choisir le type de paquetage</h5>
                  {{form_widget(form.paq, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control subject'} }) }}<br>
         </div>
             <p class="text-center">
              <button type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value=""  class="btn btn-primary" ><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Ajouter </button>
              </p>
          {{form_end(form)}}
         </form>
```

**Controller**

```
 public function createAction(Request $request, $id)
{   

  $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

  $Lpanier = new LignePanier();
  $produit = $em->getRepository('CentralBundle:Produit')->find($id);
  $opProd = $em->getRepository('CentralBundle:OperationProduit')->find($id);
  $data_array = $opProd->getPaquetage();

    $form = $this->createForm('Central\CentralBundle\Form\LignePanierType', $Lpanier, array('data_array'=>$data_array));
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $paq= $form['paq']->getData(); // always null !!
    $qte= $form['qte']->getData(); // work fine
     $Lpanier->setPrixTotProd($qte*$produit->getPrixVenteTTC());


        $em->persist($Lpanier);
        $em->flush($Lpanier);

    return $this->render('CentralBundle:Default:commitSuccess.html.twig');

}
```

the list Choice display perfectly , but the problem that after submit the value of this field always get NULL in database.

I have other input in the form and they submitted perfectly!

Someone can help me please ?

Comment: Can you show us how you populate `$options['data_array']` ? And `form_start` prints a `<form ...>`, `form_end`  prints a `</form>` so you have two forms in the generated HTML, be careful.

Answer (score 0):

In your template you have opProd { 'id': opProd.produit.id } object, but in your render method you don't set this var.

Comment: the render method will display an empty twig

Comment: I think you forgot to do that : `return $this->render('CentralBundle:Default:commitSuccess.html.twig', ['opProd' => $opProd]);`

Comment: In you form declaration you need to do that : 
`$form = $this->createForm('Central\CentralBundle\Form\LignePanierType', $Lpanier, [
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('ligne_panier_create', ['id' => $id]),
            'method' => 'POST',
           'data_array'=>$data_array
        ]);`

Comment: ah thanks @Athos , it work fine by the seconde solution , update your answer to choose it as a solution :)